# Is possible to update data while displaying without removing previously added data in Angular 4

Tags: angular

1.In angular 4 I have json object as
`pMethod ={
"name" : "ABC",
"value" : "45"
}`

2.Now there is change in object as
 `pMethod ={
"name" : "ABC",
"value" : "45",
"method" : "M"
}`

3.Suppose Method is collection which is consists of multiple objects of type pMethods ex.
`Method :[{"name" : "ABC","value" : "45","method" : "M"},{"name" : "DEF","value" : "44","method" : "y"},{"name" : "XYZ","value" : "42"}]`
Here Method[2] don't have field "method".

4.In HTML file

```
<div *ngFor="let pMethods of Method>
<div>{{pMethods.name}}</div>
<div>{{pMethods.method}}</div>
<div>{{pMethods.value}}</div>
</div>
```

Here while iterating data I want to check that Which record don't have property method and at same time I want to update that record i.e. want to add property `"method" : ""`
 in that. Is it possible?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? You arent "updating" data, you are expanding your data object with a new property. What do you mean by `I want to update data while displaying it in display as well as at back end`? Have you tried something?

Comment: Why do you want to mutate your objects in the `ngFor`? Why not pre-processing your list before reaching the directive?

Comment: To avoid multiple iterations

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would suggest you against having *side effects* in your `ngFor`.

The `NgForOf` directive should only care about *iterating a list* and *create/track a template for every element* in the list. It shouldn't be responsible for mutating the objects in the list. By doing this, you are coupling your logic to the execution of the `ngFor`.

My suggestion would be to either use a pipe for processing the list in the template or preprocessing inside of your component.